# How to make clear a letter is a function?

Tags: functions, notation

How should I make clear that a symbol is a function?

Usually a function is denoted by the letter $f$ or $g$, or is directly applied to arguments (e.g. $c(x,y)$) or is implied to be a function by an operation on functions (e.g. $h \circ j$), but in my case renaming the function would be confusing and there is not a lot of context making clear that it's a function.

Could I annotate the letter in some way which makes clear that it's a function? I am thinking of something like $\widetilde{c}$ or some other symbol above the letter.

Is there some notation by which I can make clear that $c$ is a function?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest and most direct way to say that $f$ is a function is by stating it as such. Actually, even if you use the letter $f$, you should always explicitly state that $f$ denotes a function. For example, this statement:

> If $f$ is a differentiable function, then $f$ is continuous

is, by my oppinion, much better than

> If $f$ is differentiable, then $f$ is continuous.

If you are always careful to tell what type of variable each letter you introduce represents, then using "correct" symbols ($f$, $g$ for functions, $c$ for constants) is not strictly necesary.

Comment: The problem is that I first give equations for something like $c_i = x_i * w_i$, but later I derive a formula for $c$ which makes it a function of $i$. (Discrete convolution) But if there really is no notation to make clear where $c$ is a function and where it is a variable, I will have to stick to just saying it is a function, at the cost of less readability of the formulae.

Comment: Well, if you already have a constant $c$, then do NOT introduce a function $c$ with the same name, that is confusing (and, quite frankly, wrong). However, if you have constants $c_i$, then creating a function $c$ and explaining what it is is completely normal.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to indicate the domain and codomain. This makes it clear the object you're considering is a function.

Suppose $f \colon (0,1) \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable. Then $f$ is continuous.

Comment: This is my go to as well... Consider $f: A \to B$. Or, define $f: x \mapsto f(x)$